# Duda con UpdateView en Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, djangorestframework

Este seria mi modelo(`models.py`):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'profiles', null = True, blank = True)
    biography = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)
    link = models.URLField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
```

Y esta seria mi vista basada en clase(`views.py`):

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name = 'dispatch')
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['avatar', 'biography', 'link']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile')
    template_name = "registration/profile_form.html"

    def get_object(self):
        profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user = self.request.user)

        return profile
```

Bueno mi primera duda es que ¿Porque no puedo acceder a `self.object` en el método `get_object`? Según la documentacion de django:

> ***object***
>
> Cuando usas `UpdateView` tienes acceso a `self.object`, que es el objeto
>   que se está actualizando.

Aun después de que se creara la instancia no me deja acceder a `self.object`, ¿Porque sucede esto?

---

Y mi segunda duda es ¿Como es que se envía el `pk` o el `id` del objeto para reconocerlo y como consecuencia actualizarlo? Se envía los datos por el método POST?

Me refiero a esta parte del código:

```
profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user = self.request.user)
return profile
```

---

***De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ayudarte a responder tomaré como referencia [esta](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/) página, la cual define cada vista basada en clase que posee Django, de esta forma es mucho más fácil entender qué está sucediendo.

> ¿Por qué no puedo acceder a `self.object` en el método `get_object`?

Para ayudarte a responder, debes de saber que es importante conocer para qué es usado cada método, y cada uno tiene un propósito. Solo basta con echar un vistazo a los métodos `get` y `post`. Pondré el `get` como ejemplo:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Este es el código oficial de Django, y como puedes ver, `self.object` se define a partir del resultado de `self.get_object()` por lo que no tiene sentido acceder a `self.object` dentro de `self.get_object()` porque no existe. La única forma que puedas acceder a `self.object` dentro de `self.get_object()` es luego de llamarla la primera vez, es decir:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()  # aquí no hay self.object, apenas se define
    # si vuelves a llamar
    self.get_object()  # entonces, ahora si, dentro de esta función puedes acceder a self.object
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

> Aún después de que se creara la instancia no me deja acceder a `self.object`, ¿Por qué sucede esto?

Esto dependerá de en qué lugar de la clase estás llamando a `self.object`, por ejemplo, si sobre-escribes el método `get` o `post` o `form_valid` (son donde se llama) y llamas al `super` al final, probablemente arroje error, o si lo haces en un método que corre antes de correr `get`, `post`, `form_valid` tampoco existirá. Te pondré un ejemplo con el mismo método `get` pero ya dentro de tu clase y no el código de Django:

```
[INCORRECTO]
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(self.object)  # esto no existe aún
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

[CORRECTO]
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    print(self.object)  # aquí ya dejamos que el padre defina `self.object`
    return response
```

> ¿Cómo es que se envía el `pk` o el `id` del objeto para reconocerlo y como consecuencia actualizarlo?

El `pk` o `id` se envían por la url. Si ves tus archivos de url, lo más probable es que debas definir por medio de una expresión regular la forma en como Django va a capturar el pk y luce algo así: `/users/perfil/(?P<pk>\d+)$`, y esto básicamente le dije a Django que de la url va a capturar un grupo que va a ser un número y lo va a llamar `pk`.

> **Nota**: En tu caso, al ser el usuario de la sesión al que estás intentando acceder, no necesitas definir nada en tus urls para capturar el número, porque entrarías a redundar.

En un `UpdateView` esto es un trabajo que se hace automáticamente, por lo que solo con ponerlo en la url, Django será capaz de reconocer gracias al método `get_object` cual es el objeto a mostrar y a editar.

En un `UpdateView` se puede usar tanto `POST` como `PUT`, django hará el mismo trato con ambos. Si quieres, solo puedes ver como está definido el método `put`:

```
def put(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.post(*args, **kwargs)
```

***OBSERVACIONES***

Para esta línea de código, estás creando algo si no existe `get_or_create`, yo no sé si debido a tu lógica de negocio eso sea necesario, sin embargo, te recomendaría no crear objetos en este método, aún así es algo totalmente válido, es solo una recomendación personal, ya que si este método falla, no funcionará tu vista, ni el sentido de la misma, que es editar

```
profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user = self.request.user)
```

Cualquier pregunta o inquietud, no olvides en comentar y te ayudaré a responder

Comment: gran aporte...!!

Comment: En cuanto a tu respuesta sobre: ¿Cómo es que se envía el pk o el id del objeto para reconocerlo y como consecuencia actualizarlo? Entendiste mal ya que no me exprese muy bien, este es el `path` que llama a la vista: `path('profile/', ProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name = 'profile')`, como puedes ver no se pasa ningún parámetro `pk` o `id` es por eso que preguntaba como es que se pasa el `pk`? ya que en el `path` no se pasa ningún parámetro dinámico.

Comment: De igual forma en la respuesta estoy respondiendo esa pregunta al decirte que no necesitas definirlo. Lo que sucede es que tu estás accediendo al usuario por medio de la petición, cuando haces esto `Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)` en ese momento, le estás diciendo a Django que no importa el id o el pk, si no que tiene que usar el usuario que esté logeado. Recuerda que `request` es la petición y si el usuario está logeado, entonces `request.user` es el usuario. Si te sirvió la respuesta no olvides marcarla como respondida

Comment: ok entonces por que tengo que retornar `profile`?

Comment: Porque `Profile` y `User` son modelos distintos, y cuando estás creando el `UpdateView` le estás diciendo que `model = Profile`. Entonces si haces un print de `isinstance(request.user, User)` te dará `True`. Y lo que tienen en común estos dos modelos es una relación de un campo, por lo que debes hacer la consulta por usuario para obtener el perfil. Ahora, da absolutamente lo mismo en esa función hacer un return de esta forma: `return request.user.profile`. Además el valor de lo que defines en `fields` son campos de `Profile` y no de `User`

Comment: me refería a la variable que se retorna en el método `get_object` esta parte: `profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user = self.request.user)
return profile`

Comment: Es tal cual la que te digo yo, el método `get_or_create` retorna dos cosas, la primera es el objeto, y la segunda es un boolean que te dice si ese objeto fue creado o si ya existía. Si haces `isinstance(profile, Profile)` verás que sale `True`, porque `profile` es una instancia de `Profile` es decir, es un objeto de tu base de datos en la tabla de `Profile` y la retornas porque ese es el objeto que va a utilizar tu `UpdateView`, y no lo hace el solo porque quiere, si no porque tú así quisiste al momento de decir `model = Profile`, si pusieras otro modelo, tendrías que retornar otra cosa

Comment: Imprimí `profile` y medio como resultado lo siguiente: `Profile object (1)` ¿Entonces gracias al retornar `profile` es que se puede identificar el objeto a actualizar?

Comment: Exacto! para ponertelo en una vista más general `get_object` retorna el objeto con el que va a funcionar todo el `UpdateView` por eso cuando va a actualizar sabe todo acerca del registro a actualizar, y cuando va a mostrar el formulario sabe como llenar los campos y todo

Comment: OK y tengo otra duda ¿Como es que el método `get_object` tiene acceso o recibe `self.request`?

Comment: Al intentar responderte eso, puede que te pueda confundir, solo quiero que sepas que eso no es algo necesario de saber, el trabajo de Django es que la petición o el `request` llegue a tu vista. Sin embargo si quieres curiosear mira el método [as_view](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#as_view) para qué veas en qué momento lo asigna. Pero el momento en el que lo crea depende de muchas cosas que están por fuera de la pregunta inicial y para la que si quieres puedes abrir otro hilo

Comment: OK tengo una ultima duda, La manera en que se identifica al objeto a actualizar en el `UpdateView` es por el objeto o por el `pk` cuando se retornar `profile`? Porque cuando se retorna `profile` retornamos el objeto y el `pk` no?

Comment: Es por el objeto, ya teniendo el objeto, si quisieras obtener el pk sería hacer `self.object.pk` y como te das cuenta estás haciendo un `return profile` y no un `return profile.pk`

Comment: Osea `profile` no retorna un `pk`? porque al momento de imprimir `profile` me sale esto: `Profile object (1)` ese uno debería ser un `pk` no?

Comment: Julio, Muchas de las preguntas que me estás haciendo son válidas y entiendo tus dudas, pero no hacen parte de este hilo cuando puedes abrir uno nuevo donde se puede hacer una mejor explicación que por comentarios. En el comentario anterior te dije que retornaba un objeto y no un pk, y que si querías acceder al pk podías hacer `self.object.pk`

Comment: Ok disculpa mi ignorancia, gracias por resolver mis dudas!

Comment: No eres ignorante, es válido tener dudas, todos las hemos tenido, y es mejor preguntar a quedarte con la duda

Comment: Ok muchas gracias!