# ¿Porque user_username? Django

Tags: django, django-models, djangorestframework

Tengo una duda al momento de mandar un objeto a mi `DetailView`:

```
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'profiles/profile_detail.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=self.kwargs['username'])
```

Este seria mi el modelo `Profile`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = custom_upload_to, null = True, blank = True)
    biography = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)
    link = models.URLField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
```

Mi primera duda es ¿A cual campo estoy haciendo referencia en esta parte del codigo?: `...,user_username=self...)`, Estoy haciendo referencia al campo `username` del modelo `User` o al campo `user` del modelo `Profile`?

---

Mi segunda duda es ¿Porque hay hacer referencia a este campo de esta manera extraña?: `user__username`

---

Y bueno mi ultima duda, es ¿Como es que recibe el método `get_object` el diccionario `self.kwargs`? y como es que en ese diccionario se encuentra el `username` de usuario? También vi que se podía acceder al `pk` del objeto, atraves del `self.kwargs`, pero yo no recibo el `pk`, ¿A que se debe eso?.

---

***De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te ayudaré a responder y te pondré de referencia [esta](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/) página la cual siempre uso de referencia para *Django Class Based Views*. Todo lo que te responderé lo saco de ahí, es cuestión de interpretar el código y verás la respuesta de cada pregunta.

> Mi primera duda es ¿A cuál campo estoy haciendo referencia en esta parte del código?

Algo muy increíble de la ORM de Django es precisamente como maneja los "queries" (consultas a la base de datos) y una de sus características es la forma en la que obtiene y consulta las tablas relacionadas al modelo. En este caso, tienes un modelo llamado `Profile` con un campo en su tabla que tiene una relación de uno a uno con la tabla `User`. Esto en lógica quiere decir que un usuario tiene un solo perfil, y de la misma forma un perfil pertenece solo a un usuario.

Para responder tu pregunta, tu haces dos afirmaciones, y ambas son correctas. Si estás haciendo referencia al campo `username` de `User` y a la vez al campo `user` de `Profile`, ¿Por qué? porque cuando vas a realizar una consulta a la base de datos, normalmente quieres hacer un `WHERE` y filtrar los datos que deseas, en este caso quieres obtener un registro de tu tabla `Profile` pero el parámetro que tienes para hacer la búsqueda en tu base de datos no hace referencia a la tabla `PROFILE` si no `USER`. Es decir, tu tienes es el `username` del usuario. En Django esto es posible.

Te explico más a fondo, tu podrías consultar un perfil dado un usuario, con el id del usuario, de esta forma:

```
Profile.objects.get(user=1)
```

Podrías hacerlo simplemente con un objeto `User`, de esta forma:

```
user = User.objects.first()
Profile.objects.get(user=user)
```

Pero también, podrías hacerlo consultando los campos del modelo `User`

```
Profile.objects.get(user__id=1)
# si te das cuenta esta consulta es igual a Profile.objects.get(user=1)
```

¿Eso que quiere decir? Que también puedes consultar por cualquier otro campo que pertenezca a `User`:

```
Profile.objects.get(user__username='Julio')
Profile.objects.get(user__email='email.mail@mail.com')
Profile.objects.get(user__password='123456')  # hasta por contraseña si quieres
```

Django utiliza la expresión `__` cuando tu quieres hacer referencia a los campos que pertenecen a una tabla relacionada. Es decir, como puedes ver en el ejemplo, ni `username`, ni `email` ni `password` pertenecen a la tabla `Profile`, por lo que yo debo especificar en la consulta a que tabla van. quedando una estructura así

```
"user" (la relacion) + "__" (Le decimos a Django que en la consulta haga un join) + "username" (un campo que solo puede pertenecer a "User")
"user__username" <== Este es el resultado
```

Al final esto se traduce en decirle esto a Django: "Django, tráeme el registro perfil que teniendo una relación a la tabla `User` tenga un `User.username` igual al valor que te especifique"

*Otra forma de hacer esto mismo es la siguiente: `User.objects.get(username=self.kwargs['username']).profile`*

Entonces respondiendo nuevamente a tu pregunta, **SI** si haces referencia al campo `user` del modelo `Profile` y **SI** también haces referencia al campo `username` del modelo `User` gracias a que con `__` puedes hacer un join.

> ¿Por qué hay hacer referencia a este campo de esta manera extraña?

De pronto no puedo llegar al por qué, digamos que la gente que desarrolló Django así lo determinó. Pero es la forma de hacerlo, y ha funcionado bien para todos hasta el momento. Yo que he tenido la experiencia de trabajar con varios frameworks y ORMs como Laravel, WordPress, Waterline, Sequelize y otros más, me parece que Django es quien mejor administra las consultas y los joins. Solo es cuestión de entenderlo un poco más para que puedas ver el potencial que esto tiene.

> ¿Como es que recibe el método `get_object` el diccionario `self.kwargs`?

Si ves la página que te recomiendo que leas, verás que es `DetailView` es una clase, por lo que afirmar que `get_object` recibe `self.kwargs` no es del todo válido, ya que `self` es la instancia y `kwargs` es una propiedad de esa instancia. De hecho, el lugar en donde se setea esa propiedad es el en método `as_view`, si lees hay una línea donde determina `self.kwargs = kwargs` y dichos kwargs vienen de la configuración de las urls, por lo que `DetailView` no lo llena, si no que lo recibe en algún otra parte del código de Django que no merece ser explicado, porque como en una respuesta ya te dije, **No es necesario saber cómo Django construye el `request`, eso es el asunto de Django y debemos confiar en el, esto siempre y cuando no necesitemos algún tipo de metadatos del request.**

> ¿Cómo es que en ese diccionario se encuentra el `username` de usuario? También vi que se podía acceder al `pk` del objeto, a través del `self.kwargs`, pero yo no recibo el `pk`, ¿A qué se debe eso?

Hay una pregunta que no podré responderte y es la razón por la cual el `username` te está llegando por ahí. La verdad eso dependerá de la configuración de tus urls, como ya te respondí en [Duda con UpdateView en Django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/261783/15252) el hecho de que puedas recibir parámetros en la url dependerá de tu expresión regular en la url. Te invito a que leas nuevamente tu pregunta anterior y puedas ver como funciona lo que recibes en la url de acuerdo a los grupos en la expresión regular. Lo más probable es que no tengas un `pk` porque en las urls no tienes algo como esto: `(?P<pk>\d+)`. Pero si quieres, puedes adjuntar el código de tus urls para ayudarte a responder mejor este punto.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, entendí perfectamente!

Comment: Pero me surge otra duda, esta es la `url` que llama a la  `DetailView`: `path('<username>/', ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),` mi duda es ¿Como es que esa `url` recibe el parámetro `username`?

Comment: Tengo una `ListView` que devuelve una lista de las instancias de `Profile`, ¿Capas la `ListView` le pasa el `username` a la url?

Comment: Y cuando llamas la url en el navegado como sale? Es decir, cual es la url en el navegador cuando visitas ese sitio:?

Comment: Asi cuando entro al `DetailView`: `/profiles/lcteen/`, 'lcteen' seria el `user`

Comment: Bueno, entonces ya tienes la respuesta a la pregunta, al definir la url como `'<username>'` le estás diciendo a Django que cuando reciba una url que empiece por `/profiles/` la capturará y guardará todo lo que le sigue a eso y lo empaquetará dentro de `this.kwargs`, es por eso que cuando haces `/profiles/lcteen/` tienes que `this.kwargs['username']` es igual a `lcteen`, intenta definier la url como `'<pk>'` y en vez de poner `lcteen` pon el pk o el id del perfil, y luego verifica el valor en `this.kwargs`. Esto se logra gracias a las expresiones regulares

Comment: Ok entiendo eso, la duda que tengo es ¿Quien le envía el parámetro a la ur? osea quien envía el parámetro a `<username>`

Comment: Tu, tu eres el que está programando la url, al momento de crear el link que te dirige a esa página, en algún momento le dices a Django que ponga ahí el username del usuario

Comment: Ahhh cierto me olvidaba, perdón por esa pregunta  un poco tonta, gracias por resolver mi dudas!