# Consulta Django 2 tablas relacionadas

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

Tengo un problema en Django, **no se como hacer una consulta entre 2 tablas de Django**, os pongo el código por que no soy capaz de hacer lo que necesito.

La aplicación es fácil, se trata de traer un listado de ciudades y cuando pincho en una de ellas me devuelva un template con el listado de las poblaciones de esa ciudad/provincia. Ambos modelos están relacionados con una clave foranea.

Necesito pasar a traves de GET url el nombre de la ciudad, asi `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cadiz/`, y recogerla en la view population_list.

No se que estoy haciendo mal, no entiendo bien, no quiero usar el ID, en la url, necesito usar el nombre.

**Models**

```
class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ciudades'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city


class Population(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    population = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:

        verbose_name_plural = 'Poblaciones'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.population
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import City
from .models import Population

# Create your views here.
def city_list(request):

    citys = City.objects.filter(active='1').order_by('city')
    return render(request, 'satrent/city_list.html', {'citys' : citys})

def population_list(request, city):

    populations = Population.objects.select_related('city').get(city=city)
    return render(request, 'satrent/population_list.html', {{'populations' : populations}})
```

**urls,py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.city_list, name='city_list'),
    path('<city>/', views.population_list, name='population_list'),

]
```

**templates**

**city_list.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <h1><a href="/">Inicio</a></h1>
</div>

{% for city in citys %}
    <div>
        <p> city: {{ city.city }}</p>
        <h2><a href="{% url 'population_list' city.city %}">{{ city.slug }}</a></h2>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

**population_list.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <h1><a href="/">Inicio</a></h1>
</div>

{% for population in populations %}
    <div>
    <p>aqui {{ population.id }}</p>
        <p> city: {{ population.city_id }}</p>
        <p> population: {{ population.slug }}</p>
        <p> popualtion: {{ population.population }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada si quieres pasar el nombre de la ciudad como argumento a la URL, lo ideal es que el nombre de la ciudad (`city`) sea único, para así evitar errores:

```
class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    ...
```

Una ves hecho esto, tu vista `population_list`, debería quedar así:

```
def population_list(request, city):

    populations = Population.objects.get(city__city = city).select_related('city')
    return render(request, 'satrent/population_list.html', {'populations' : populations})
```

> Por cierto cuidado al momento de pasar el contexto al template, estas haciendo
>   esto:
>
> ```
> {{'populations' : populations}}
> ```
>
> Esto daría error ya que no es un diccionario valido, debe ser así:
>
> ```
> {'populations' : populations}
> ```

---

Por otra parte, con `city__city`, hacemos referencia al campo `city`, de la relación `city` (modelo `City`), puede ser algo confuso, debido a que el modelo `City` tiene un campo llamado `city`, te recomiendo cambiarlo a `name`, así no es tan confuso, ademas de que es mas legible. Si en dado caso lo haces la, query debería ser así:

```
Population.objects.get(city__name = city).select_related('city')
```

Mucho mas legible.

Una ves hecho esto tu template debería que dar así:

```
{% for population in populations %}
    <div>
    <p>aqui {{ population.id }}</p>
        <!-- Recuerda que "population.city_id" es el id de la tabla relacionada "City" -->
        <p> city: {{ population.city_id }}</p> 
        <p> population: {{ population.slug }}</p>
        <p> popualtion: {{ population.population }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Recuerda que cuando tu quieres hacer referencia a los campos que pertenecen a una tabla relacionada, utiliza la expresión `__`, si no entiendes muy bien te sugiero revisar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/262341/porque-user-username-django), donde se explica, con mas detalle.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ha valido perfectamente, solo un apunte `populations = Population.objects.get(city__name = city).select_related('city')`, lo he cambiado a `populations = Population.objects.filter(city__name=name).select_related('city')`, get() por filter(), por que me daba este error, y buscando he encontrado este link, [enlace]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063748/django-get-returned-more-than-one-topic[enlace]. Muchas gracias

Comment: El error es porque el método `.get()` retorno mas de una instancia (por eso te dije que `city` sea único, justamente para evitar estos errores), pero es valido lo que hiciste. Un gusto ayudarte! Saludos! :)